# What is the proper way to use filters?

Tags: angularjs

I get an issue using `$filter('filter')` of AngularJS. It seems not working when I have an empty cell in the line...

When a cell is empty on a line if I add a filter it works but when removing the filter the line with the empty cell is deleted from `contacts`...

AngularJS script :

```
app.controller("ContactNgController", function($scope, $http, $filter, $document) {
  $http.get('/api/mes-contacts').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.contacts = data.contacts;
    $scope.filteredContacts = data.contacts;
    $scope.nbContacts = data.contacts.length;
    $scope.limit = data.limit;

    $scope.onChange = function(){
      $scope.contacts = data.contacts;
      $scope.filteredContacts = $filter('filter')($scope.contacts, $scope.search);
    };
  });
});
```

Table HTML :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Prénom<input type="text" ng-model="search.firstname" placeholder="Recherche par prénom" ng-change="onChange()" autocomplete="off"></th>
    <th>Nom<input type="text" ng-model="search.lastname" placeholder="Recherche par nom" ng-change="onChange()" autocomplete="off"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:search | limitTo:limit">
    <td>{{contact.firstname}}</td>
    <td>{{contact.lastname}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Contacts array]
<sub>(source: [zupimages.net](http://zupimages.net/up/15/43/52mu.png))</sub>

Comment: it's not working. you need to import the angular scripts

Comment: I can't share the whole code. But there is the main issue...

Comment: My point is that you need to provide the minimal information to simulate your problem, for instance: contacts array, search values.

Comment: Edit : the entire AngularJS script.

Comment: Nice! just share the contacts array, so we can see how the structure for this variable.

Comment: Edit : the contacts array from the API